C# cadena de conexión a base de datos FirebirdSQL en docker
Estoy hace días tratando de conectar mi API en C# a una base de datos FirebirdSQL (v4) que está en un contenedor de Docker.
A través de DBeaver logro la conexión con ésta cadena
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3055//firebird/data/stocksf2desarrollo.FDB

la ubicación en Docker es

Desde al appsettings estoy usando
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "desarrollo": "Server=localhost;User=SYSDBA;Password=a73b4d0dac12e8c75429;Database=localhost/3055:/firebird/data/stocksf2desarrollo;Port=3055;Dialect=1;Charset=NONE;"

Y no logro la conexión, probé otras variantes y tampoco.
Dejo la configuracion que tengo sobre la ruta en firebird.conf
# Type: string (special format)
# desactivo esto
DatabaseAccess = Restrict /firebird/data
#DatabaseAccess = Full

Traté con el acceso Full y no tuve resultados.
Desde ya, gracias por cualquier ayuda que puedan proporcionar.
Saludos!

localhost significa literalmente "este equipo" o "este servidor", pues local hace referencia a la misma máquina y se utiliza habitualmente cuando vas a establecer una conexión a un puerto local a través de la interfaz de red loopback.
Viendo el contenedor de docker como una máquina virtual, no puedes conectarte o referirte a los puertos dentro del contenedor como localhost, a menos que estés ejecutando dentro del contenedor.
Recuerda que cada contenedor tiene su propia dirección IP. De la documentación de la dirección IP de un contenedor docker

By default, the container gets an IP address for every Docker network it attaches to. A container receives an IP address out of the IP subnet of the network. The Docker daemon performs dynamic subnetting and IP address allocation for containers. Each network also has a default subnet mask and gateway

Mi traducción libre:

Por defecto, el contenedor obtiene una dirección IP por cada red Docker a la que se conecte. El contenedor recibe una dirección IP de la misma subred. El demonio de Docker realiza subredes y asignación de direcciones IP de manera dinámica para los contenedores. Cada red también tiene una mascara y puerta de enlace predeterminadas.

Puedes obtener la IP asignada a un contenedor con el comando:
docker inspect \
  -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' nombre_o_id_del_contenedor

(en Windows utiliza comillas dobles en lugar de simples para rodear las llaves).
En resumen, sustituye la palabra localhost en tu cadena de conexión por la IP del contenedor, por ejemplo:
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "desarrollo": "Server=192.168.14.78;User=SYSDBA;Password=a73b4d0dac12e8c75429;Database=/firebird/data/stocksf2desarrollo;Port=3055;Dialect=1;Charset=NONE;"

Nota que también he quitado la palabra localhost de la dirección de la base de datos, pues vamos a utilizar directamente el archivo principal de la base de datos almacenado dentro del contenedor.
Una observación lateral es que, no veo razón para, a estas alturas del partido, conectarte a una base de datos utilizando dialecto versión 1, que te limita en muchas de las características modernas del motor. A menos que tengas una razón de peso para usarlo, mi sugerencia es que uses dialecto 3.

Hola, muchas gracias, desde que pusiste la respuesta estoy tratando de establecer la conexión, pero sin éxito, el error que tengo ahora es el siguiente ---- I/O error during "open" operation for file "/firebird/data/stocksf2desarrollo"
Error while trying to open file ----, gracias nuevamente por la ayuda!!!

Existe el archivo? Tiene permisos el usuario del motor? Has establecido una conexión local, (dentro del contenedor)?

Si, está todo en orden, de hecho, logro conectarme a la base desde el DBeaver con esta cadena "jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3055//firebird/data/stocksf2desarrollo.FDB",  hice importación de datos y corregí algunos temas de tipos de datos en los SPs sin problemas.

A primera vista veo que en una cadena el archivo de base de datos tiene extensión y en la otra no. Es decir, no estás refiriendo la misma base de datos. Corrige la cadena del lado donde no te logras conectar. Debe ser exactamente la misma ruta y nombre de archivo en ambas.

Muchas gracias, ya está solucionado!!! Finalmente funcionó con el localhost, dejo el link que habla sobre las IP de los contenedores y junto con lo que me indicaste terminó de cerrar lo que necesitaba https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-a-docker-container-ip-address-explained-with-examples/ Gracias Totales!!!
